# How to open a fragment through android deep link from mail?

Tags: android, kotlin, email, android-fragments, deep-linking

I need to open a specific fragment in my application, on click of a confirmation link in the email app. Is it possible and if it is, could I receive  information from this link?

Comment: Yes this is possible: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all you need to add these codes in your manifest to `<activity/>`([For more information](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)):

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="@string/APP_LINKS_URL"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="@string/APP_LINKS_URL"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> `@string/APP_LINKS_URL` is url address like `some.address.com` ([For more info](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations))

After that, by clicking a link your activity starts with this link (like Uri: `intent.data`) in intent object. Based on this link you can open or navigate to the any fragment in your app. For navigating between screen you can use Navigation component [navigation-deep-link.](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link?hl=en#implicit)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    //...
    if (intent.data?.toString()?.contains(getString(R.string.APP_LINKS_URL)) == true) {
        //your logic to navigate to specify fragment
    }
}
```

And you can get informations from this link (Uri): `intent.data`